# Powershell: Need to get Event Viewer log

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to get specific logs from Event Viewer (specifically EVENT ID 1074 which is kernel-power) and need to get data for example the last 1 hour from running the script manually. So basically the script is supposed to reboot the server if it did not find event ID 1074 for the last 1 hour (hence i put in the -after (get-date).Addminutes(-60)) and write another log in the event viewer. Else if the server was able to find EVENT ID 1074 within 1 hour (60 minutes) it will just cancel and write a log.

I tried to mess around with the script by interchanging if and else statement but when running the script it reboots the machine even though there is Event ID 1074 there in the last few minutes. Thoughts?

```bsh
Clear-Host
$eventid = 109
$date = get-eventlog -logname System -InstanceId $eventid -after (get-date).Addminutes(-60) | ?{$_.Message -like "*kernel power*" }
$message = "The kernel power manager has initiated a shutdown transition."
if ( $date.count -lt 1) 
{
    write-output "Machine was restarted in the last 60 minutes, skipping machine restart/reboot."
    (get-eventlog system -Source "User32" | where-object {$_.eventid -eq 1074}) | select UserName
    Write-EventLog -LogName System -Source "Microsoft-Windows-Kernel-Power" -Message $message -EventId $eventid
} 
else
{
    write-output "Machine was not rebooted recently, restarting now..."
    write-EventLog -LogName System -Source "Microsoft-Windows-Kernel-Power" -Message "Restarted machine" -EventId 110
    Start-Sleep 15
    Restart-Computer
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd strongly suggest using [`Get-WinEvent`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.diagnostics/get-winevent) instead, it has better filtering capabilities:

```
$Filter = @{
  LogName = 'System'
  Id = 1074
  StartTime = (Get-Date).AddHours(-1)
}
$rebootEvent = Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable $Filter -MaxEvents 1 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

if($rebootEvent){
  # Reboot was initiated within the last hour
}
else{
  # Reboot
}
```

In the example above, we search for at most 1 instance of events matching the filter criteria:

- Logged to `System`
- Event Id is `1074`
- It was written *after* 1 hour ago

If nothing matches the criteria, `Get-WinEvent` throws a "Not Found" error by default, hence `-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue`.

Comment: Thanks a bunch Mathias, this was easier. You are a life saver.

Really appreciate your help!

Comment: @Sig That's great to hear! If my answer solved your problem please consider marking it "accepted" by clicking the checkmark on the left :)